# elinks | dump after form submit

Tags: shell-scripting

i'm trying to find a way, to dump the content of a page, when form is submitted by elinks.

```
/usr/bin/elinks -auto-submit 1 -eval 'set document.browse.forms.confirm_submit = 0' $LINK
```

If `-dump` is used, will export the content of the page before submiting it. The same is when we are using `>` export operator to file at the end.

I'm not looking forward for curl solution.

Thanks,